# How to create Pull request or merge PR

Tags: git, go, go-git

I'm able to clone fetch push to a repo. Similarly Is it possible to create pull request or merge PR using Go?

```
"gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"
```

Comment: Go's `net/http` can call the hosting services' REST APIs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PR's are not part of the Git core but from the Git hosting service you are using. For example, if you use Github you would need to use a Github go library for those operations,.

Answer (score 0):

used this type to create pull request

https://godoc.org/github.com/google/go-github/github#PullRequestsService.Create